# Firebase query on a large array

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Currently, I have a database with structure :

```
"companies": [
    {
      "address": "aa",
      "branch": "bbb",
      "id": 1,
      "lat": "35.669648",
      "lng": "139.785461",
      "name": "gg",
      "zip": "104-0051"
    },
    ....
  ]
```

I want to develop a function to return all companies in a radius.

- Step 1: get latitude,longitude from device
- Step 2: Retrive all companies at node "companies" from Firebase, then loop to get lat,long. After that, calculation distance, check the distance < radius return the company.

The problem is the companies is a large array. It seems to be bad solution if I use the loop.
I test on 150.000 records , it takes ~40s.
What is the best solution for this requirement?

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/geofire

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you tell me something in detail ?

Comment: Geofire is a library that allows you to query keys based on their distance to a certain location. It fits exactly with your use-case. The page cartant gave links to all three implementations of the library: iOS, Android and Web. I recommend you read the documentation for your target platform, try it and report back if you have a concrete problem.

Comment: Great! Geofire is what I need. Finally I can apply it in my projects. Thanks guys